# Reading a zip file from a GET request without saving first in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, zip

I am trying read zip file from HTTP GET request. One way to do it is by
saving the response body to a physical file first and then reading the
zip file to read the files inside the zip.

Is there a way to read the files inside directly without having to save
the zip file into a physical file first?

My current code:

```
Net::HTTP.start("clinicaltrials.gov") do |http|
  resp = http.get("/ct2/results/download?id=15002A")
  open("C:\\search_result.zip", "wb") do |file|
    file.write(resp.body)
  end
end

Zip::ZipFile.open("C:\\search_result.zip") do |zipfile|
  xml = zipfile.file.read("search_result.xml")
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [rubyzip](http://rubyzip.sourceforge.net/), which can't unzip from an in-memory buffer.

You might want to look at using [Chilkat's Ruby Zip Library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ruby-zip.asp) instead as it supports in-memory processing of zip data. It claims to be able to "Create or open in-memory Zips", though I have no experience with the library myself. Chilkat's library isn't free, however, so that may be a consideration. Not sure if there is a free library that has this feature.

Answer (score 0):

One way might be to implement in-memory file, so that RubyZip can still play with your file without changing anything.

You sould take a look at [this Ruby Hack](http://skipmeamadeus.blogspot.com/2008/01/ruby-hack-in-memory-files-with-metadata.html)